# Template include tag: Choose another template if it does not exist

Tags: python, django, templates

I would like to include a different template depending request. For example:

Suppose that request has:

```
request.country = 'Spain'
request.city = 'Madrid'
```

I want to include "index.html" view but:

---- If myapp/index_madrid.html exist

```
{% include "myapp/index_madrid.html" %}
```

---- elif myapp/index_spain.html exist

```
   {% include "myapp/index_spain.html" %}
```

---- else  go to default version

```
   {% include "myapp/index.html" %}
```

How can I achieve this behaviour in a transparent way? I mean, I would like to do something like:

```
{% my_tag_include "myapp/index.html" %}
{% my_tag_include "myapp/another_view.html" with p='xxx' only%}
{% my_tag_include "myapp/any_view.html" with p='sss' a='juan' %}
```

and achieve the cascading loading that I explained before.

Thanks

Comment: you can attach a variable in context by checking template in view and check `{% if var %}`  in template

Comment: What have you tried? You obviously have a very strict set of requirements. Three people have tried to help you, and you're dissatisfied. It would be easier to directly target what you need if you provide an example of what you've tried to solve the problem

Comment: Sorry rnevious. What I need is simply to render the template view that I want by only making one call such as:
{% my_tag_include "myapp/another_view.html" with p='xxx' only%}

Its been quite easy to make those "templates fallbacks" when rendering a normal html from a view function as I can overwrite the template_name on "process_template_response" middleware function. However, I cannot find a similar-elegant way to do it when inluding partial views inside templates. The main problem that I have found is that filters dont have access to request object.

Comment: I have also tried to create a custom tag "my_include" changing token and calling "do_include" function as "include" tag does, but I cannot do that because I need the request object to be able to change the token and call "do_include" function (but this functino is called on compilation time and not on execution time)  :(

Answer (score 2):

you can implement a custom template tag to check the existence of the template:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


def template_exists(template_name):
    try:
        django.template.loader.get_template(template_name)
        return True
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return False
register.filter('template_exists', template_exists)
```

And in your template :

```
 {% if template_exists  "myapp/index_"add:request.city|add:".html" %}
     {% include "myapp/index_"add:request.city|add:".html" %}
 {% elif template_exists  "myapp/index_"add:request.country|add:".html" %}
     {% include "myapp/index_"add:request.country|add:".html" %}
 {% else %}
      {% include "myapp/index.html" %}
```

**Edit** :
You can do all your logic through the template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def existing_template(context):
    request = context["request"]
    if django.template.loader.get_template("myapp/index_"+ request.city+".html"):
        return "myapp/index_"+ request.city+".html"
    elif  django.template.loader.get_template("myapp/index_"+ request.country+".html"):
        return "myapp/index_"+ request.country+".html"
    else:
        return "myapp/index.html"
```

And in your template :

```
{% include required_template %}
```

Comment: Thanks Amr but the thing is that I dont want to write so much code on the template. I would like to do something like:

 {% my_tag_include "myapp/index.html %}

and this custom tags will be responsible for every logic and will return the rendered view that best fits.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Its much better Amr but where would you call to "existing_template" tag? I mean, we need something like this:

{% include existing_template("myapp/index.html") %}

Comment: you can pass just "index" to the custom tag , and construct the template path there  , I mean the template tag can return ( "myapp/" + template_prefix + "_"+ request.city+".html" )

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to implement this kind of logic in the view:

```
# views.py
from django.template.loader import select_template

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        include_template = select_template([
            'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(request.city),
            'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(request.country),
            'myapp/index.html'
        ])

        ctx = {
            'include_template': include_template
        }

        return render(request, 'myapp/base.html', ctx)

# myapp/base.html
{% include include_template %}
```

**[select_template()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine.select_template)** will return the first template in the passed list that exists. The `include` tag supports including compiled templates beginning from `Django 1.7`, so this should work fine if you are on 1.7 or above.

---

**Update: Reuse across multiple views**

```
# utils.py
from django.template.loader import select_template

def get_approriate_template(tokens, app_name):
    templates = ['{}/index_{}.html'.format(app_name, x) for x in tokens]
    templates.append('{}/index.html'.format(app_name))
    return select_template(templates)

# views.py
from .utils import get_approriate_template

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        tokens = [request.city, request.country]
        ctx = {
            'include_template': get_appropriate_template(tokens, app_name='myapp')
        }

        return render(request, 'myapp/base.html', ctx)
```

---

**Update: Rendering template from a template tag**

```
# templatetags/myapp_extras.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def my_tag_include(context):
    from django.template.loader import select_template
    include_template = select_template([
        'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].city),
        'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].country),
        'myapp/index.html'
    ])
    return include_template.render(context)

# myapp/base.html
{% load myapp_extras %}
{% my_tag_include %}
```

Comment: This would be a good choice if this only happened in one view, however, this happens many times on my site (many views and many including templates) so this solution is not very appropiate.

Comment: @alvaro.rmfg then write a context processor or a mixin. This seems like a great solution.

Comment: Thanks rnevious. This solution is better, however it forces me to change every view code whenever I add new templates to my code. The solution I am looking for is to write:
{% my_tag_include "myapp/index.html" %}  and this would magically choose the view that best fits taking into account variables from the request.

Comment: Selecting a template based on some criteria really should live in the view layer, not the template. I think this answer has the best approach to the initial problem. Maybe use the `ContextMixin` logic and overload `get_context_data()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing your own template tag which returns the valid template which exists.

**Method-1 Using `assignment_tag`:**

**some_app/templatetags/some_app_extras.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import select_template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_valid_template(context):
    city_template = 'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].city)
    country_template = 'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].country)
    index_template = 'myapp/index.html'
    templates_list = [city_template, country_template, index_template]
    valid_template = select_template(templates_list)
    return valid_template.name
```

**In your template:**

```
{% load some_app_extras %}
{% get_valid_template as valid_template %}
{% include valid_template %}
```

We use assignment tag for it and pass the context to it by passing `takes_context=True` argument when registering the tag. Since we have the context, we can access the `request` to get the `city` and `country`. After this, we use the `select_template()` function of django and pass it a list of templates which will return the first template found in the list.

Then in our template, we can use this template tag to get the `valid template` and use this variable to render the `valid template`.

**Method-2 Using `simple_tag`:**

If you want to do the rendering in 1 line only as you mentioned in the comments, then you can use `simple_tag`. You don't need to assign the template name in a variable then for the rendering to be done by `include` built-in template tag later. `get_template_tag`  will automatically display the necessary template since it has been already been rendered in the template tag code.

**some_app/templatetags/some_app_extras.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import select_template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_valid_template(context):
    city_template = 'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].city)
    country_template = 'myapp/index_{}.html'.format(context['request'].country)
    index_template = 'myapp/index.html'
    templates_list = [city_template, country_template, index_template]
    valid_template = select_template(templates_list)
    return valid_template.render(context)
```

**In your template:**

```
{% load some_app_extras %}   
{% get_valid_template %}
```

Comment: This is almost what I need but doing two calls on every partial template is a bit.... Would it be any way to do something like:
{% include "myapp/index.html"|get_valid_template %}  or somethin like that??

The best solution would be something like:
{% my_custom_include_tag "myapp/index.html" %}  and this would make every logic and include the specific view.  Would it be any possibility to achieve that?

Comment: You are doing only 1 call in a template by this `{% get_valid_template as valid_template %}`. You can  get the valid template name in the template by `{{valid_template}}`. `{% get_valid_template as valid_template %}` will call the `get_valid_template` tag and assign the returned value to `valid_template`. This variable now can be used anywhere in the template.

Comment: yeah I know, but that way I need two lines every time I need any templates. The first line to make the assignment and the second one to include that template. Its the best way I have read until now but I would like something a bit more elegant, just making a call and getting rendered the specific template.

Comment: Try `{% include get_valid_template %}` if that works. If you need to access the returned template again, you would have to make the call again. I had assigned it if you need to use it anywhere in the same template again. You don't need to do  similar to `{% include "myapp/index.html"|get_valid_template %}` because i have added `index.html` in the list of templates in the template tag.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get your last response :(

Comment: **I have tried with the assignment tag , its working**. Yes, you would have to write two lines because if you want to use `{% include "myapp/index.html"|get_valid_template %}`, then  in `get_valid_template(context)`, value of `context` will be `"myapp/index.html"`. Then you won't be able to access request or more precisely the context. To access context, you have to use `simple_tag` or `assignment_tag`.

Comment: Also `{% include {% get_valid_template %} %}` will be invalid if we try to use `simple_tag`. `include` will not be able to understand.

Comment: Were you able to get what i was saying?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by creating a custom simple tag, such as:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def my_own_include(context, *args):
    #I get the request and create a list of possible template views
    return select_template(list_of_posible_views).render(context)
```

On the .html file I would call this tag like:

```
{% my_own_include 'index.html' %}
```

Thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: Aren't you getting an error `'my_own_include' received too many positional arguments` using this?

Comment: Updated the ans to include both the approaches using `simple_tag` and `assignment_tag`.

Comment: You are right, I get that error but I have solved using *args params. See the edited response please. Thx!

Comment: Yep, it is correct. Though `{% my_own_include %}` will also work if you define `index.html` in your template tag code. Otherwise, you would have to write `index.html` everytime you are using that template tag. Use whatever suits you. :)